# IIS 7.5 Unable to write configuration file

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, configuration, iis-7.5

I have a fault regarding IIS 7.5 on Win Server 2008 R2, whenever I try to change any site bindings or start an application pool I get the error below:

```
Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
Error: Cannot write configuration file
```

the application pools run as network service. None of the sites that are running have been affected however their configuration cannot be changed

**UPDATED 05/10/2012**

A reboot fixed this issue, however I am curious to know what caused it in the first place.

**UPDATE 09/04/2013**
The server is no longer in production.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the applicationHost.config file?

Comment: Yes the permissions where fine, but I am still interested in any answers as to the cause.

Comment: In my case, the server had run out of free space, and freeing up space fixed the problem.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem - turned out we'd just run out of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

App Fabric can cause a Issue like that:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1178705.aspx/1

Comment: Thanks for the info, however app fabric is not installed. Please see comments on above question, the question is no longer relevant to me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had any changes to your virus protection policy lately? The actual file that can't be written to is at c:\users\\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress. I had our security team re-open access to that directory, just for developers and that fixed it.